# List datasets in the memory workspace in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, list, workspace, in-memory

I have some sensitive data which I would prefer to only exist in memory that I wish to use in ArcGIS Pro. Loading the data into the "memory" workspace is no problem, and so is deleting it, but managing large numbers of layers in memory is problematic.

**In ArcGIS Pro, is there any way to list the data available in the "memory" workspace?**

Deleting the associated layers does not remove the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was cross posted to [List data in "memory" workspace -- Esri Community](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/list-data-in-quot-memory-quot-workspace/m-p/1151948#M52556), and below is my reply over there.

> Not all ArcPy functions that work with workspaces, e.g.,
> ListFeatureClasses, work with the new "memory" workspace.  ArcPy DA
> Walk usually does if you know the underlying name of the workspace and
> not its "memory" alias.  Try:
>
> `next(arcpy.da.Walk("InMemoryDB\GPProMemoryWorkspace"))`

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
import arcpy,os
from arcpy import env
theWS='in_memory'
env.workspace = theWS
features = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print features
```

works fine in ArcGIS 10.8:

[image]

Comment: this works for "in_memory" but not the newer "memory" workspace. from what I understand, the "in_memory" workspace actually writes some data to disk